# Battlefield 3 Trailer Sound Design - Type of Synthesis

Tags: synthesis, trailer

Hi!

BF3 has just released a new cool video and it as always has a great sound design:
[youtube]qDJdE88OX-0[/youtube]

There is an interesting sequence from 00:05 to 00:10 sec and I wonder what kind of synthesis is used there? Granular, FM or something else?

Right now I am experimenting only with fm-synth and I don't know anything about granular method. And, if aforementioned moment was created by granular synthesizer, then I'm starting to learn it immediately! :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked Ben Minto and his anser was:
fast edits and filter - keeping it old school and doing it manually  will double check though - that was done 18 months or more ago.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like some form of subtractive noise synthesis with a stutter effect applied. This could be done by applying a LFO shaped as a square wave to the volume of the synth, and then automating the speed of the LFO. There are also filter sweeps happening underneath.

Cheers,
~Matt

Comment: So, I guess as always there is nothing supernatural and all done with simple things.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't dismiss it as easy to duplicate, but you certainly can create a similar effect with most software synths, as long as the synths have enough flexibility. When I wrote this reply I was thinking specifically in terms of Camel Audio's Alchemy synth. Short of shoving an all-out endorsement in your face, Alchemy is extremely  flexible and, in my opinion, perfect for a task like this.

Answer (score 1):

hmm, sounds like some sort of static, with lfo on LP filter(lfo rate modulated too), maybe a little bit of doppeler. imo innitial sound is some basic noisy synth patch(it could be even basic subtractive synth) or static noise.

edit: low pass filtering doesn't work for noise oscillators as i would thought, but small short notes of just noise osc and a little bit of doppeler does similar results.

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be any number of things, perhaps it's designed using recordings and not synthesis at all. As the other answers have mentioned there's some heavy amplitude modulation present and this contributes a great deal to the character of the sound. Recording a few minutes of de-tuning a radio or other glitch source and playing around with LFO rate AM should give some similar results. As the effect changes the sound so dramatically it's also good to have a long sample to experiment on - you never know what combination of sound and modulation rate are going to be the most fruitful.

I think the neat thing here is how they've used bursts of the sound to punctuate the key moments of the sequence with an increase in the rate of modulation to create the accelerando effect.

Thanks for posting, would be an interesting sound to try and re-create.

Answer (score 1):

"The base of the sound is a recording of an old radio scanning through frequencies. So mostly noise and static but with inherent movement. This is treated with distortion, filtersweeps (FilterFreak LPF) and an aggressive stutter effect (SoundToys Tremolator) with the tempo automated over time."